# Java process inside a loop and file output

Tags: java, file

If I have a loop and inside it a process then output to a file , after the loop end close file . The program have been running for a while , but since close file after the loop , when I open the output file no output was there . Is there a way I can see the output or I can stop the program and let it write what it has processed to the output file ?

```
for ( int i =0 ; i < 1000 ; i +++)
{

// do some calculations 

fileoutput.write(...);
}
fileoutput.close();
```

Comment: try to flush the output stream after `.write()`.

Comment: I suggest you should clarify your question this is somewhat muddled but it is only my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the program is producing some output, but is buffering it, there's no way to externally prod it into flushing the buffer.

Your best bet is to modify the loop to call `fileoutput.flush()`, and re-run:

```
for ( int i =0 ; i < 1000 ; i +++)
{
  ...
  fileoutput.write(...);
  fileoutput.flush();
}
fileoutput.close();
```

This way you'll be able to see the data appear in the file as it gets written.

Answer (score 1):

Try to [flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush%28%29) the file after each iteration.

Also make use of the **try catch finally** pattern when using writers. Scrap the last with Java7 and use [Try with resources](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2011/03/java-7-try-with-auto-closable-resources/).

Answer (score 1):

In every step the last data added the output file. So only the last data you can find in the file. Do not forget flush and make the writer appendence is true .